# I have multiple sections on my visualforce page. Each with a button called 'Mark as Done' when I click on it a 'Done' image appears in place of it

Tags: apex, visualforce

Controller Code:

```
public boolean showConfimImg {get;set;
public boolean showConfimImg1 {get;set;}
public boolean showConfimImg2 {get;set;}
public boolean showConfimImg3 {get;set;}

public pageReference markComplete() {
    showConfimImg = true;
    return null;
}

public pageReference markComplete1() {
    showConfimImg1 = true;
    return null;
}

public pageReference markComplete2() {
    showConfimImg2 = true;
    return null;
}

public pageReference markComplete3() {
    showConfimImg3 = true;
    return null;
}
```

// in constructer

```
showConfimImg = false;
```

// Vf Page Code

```
<!--For every section I have added this-->
    <apex: commandButton style = "float:right;" value = "Mark as Completed" action = "{!markComplete}" rerender = "form" rendered = "{!NOT(showConfimImg)}"/>
    <apex: outputPanel style = "float:right;" rendered = "{!showConfimImg}">
    <apex: image value = "/img/msg_icons/confirm32.png"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>
```

How do I avoid this redundancy?

Comment: I didn't get your question. could you please elaborate more?

Comment: I have multiple methods written in my controller which are performing exactly the same task. I want to avoid doing it in that way

Comment: then just use only one method in you controller and call that method from all your sections.. what is issue you are facing?

Comment: @Ratan in that case all sections are marked as done. As I am referring a single image

Comment: Yes. This way it will display all but you can take a variable in controller and when you click on button just use param to set the section no to that variable. Now in your method just check that variable and identify, from which button this method called and based on that just make the boolean true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can take a variable in controller and when you click on button just use param to set the section no to that variable. Now in your method just check that variable and identify, from which button this method called and based on that just make the boolean true.

Below is just example. This is not complete and compiled code. Just trying to show you the logic

```
<apex:commandbutton >
    <apex;param name ="somthing" value="1" assignTo="{!intSectionNum}" />
</apex:commandbutton >

<apex:commandbutton >
    <apex;param name ="somthing1" value="2" assignTo="{!intSectionNum}" />
</apex:commandbutton >

<apex:commandbutton >
    <apex;param name ="somthing2" value="3" assignTo="{!intSectionNum}" />
</apex:commandbutton >

<apex:commandbutton >
    <apex;param name ="somthing3" value="4" assignTo="{!intSectionNum}" />
</apex:commandbutton >
```

in your controller

```
public boolean showConfimImg {get;set;
public boolean showConfimImg1 {get;set;}
public boolean showConfimImg2 {get;set;}
public boolean showConfimImg3 {get;set;}
public Integer intSectionNum    {get;set;}

public pageReference markComplete3() {

    if(intSectionNum == 1)
        showConfimImg = true;
    else if(intSectionNum == 2)
        showConfimImg1 = true;
    else if(intSectionNum == 3)
        showConfimImg2 = true;
    else 
        showConfimImg3 = true;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: But will it work if i want multiple sections selected at once?

Comment: @AJINKYARAUT . I guess you can't click on all buttons at a same time ? is it ?

Comment: Please find the screenshot: http://imgur.com/YarrtjV

Comment: @AJINKYARAUT yes I can see there are multiple buttons are there. So I guess the above solution will work for you.

Comment: Thanks..But here's what I did

Comment: //Controller
public Map<String,Boolean> markedCompMap {get;set;}

public void markAsCompleted(){
        String key = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('step');
        markedCompMap.put(key,true);
        
    }

// In Constructor
markedCompMap = new map < String, Boolean > ();
  // Add id and defualt values as false (To be used for avoiding redundant methods to show and hide done images)
  for (Integer i = 1; i <= 24; i++) {
   markedCompMap.put('step' + i, false);
  }

Comment: //On VF Page
<apex:commandButton style="float:right;" value="Mark as Completed" action="{!markAsCompleted}" rerender="form" rendered="{!NOT(markedCompMap['step1'])}" >
    <apex:param name="step" value="step1" />
</apex:commandButton>

Comment: <apex:outputPanel style="float:right;" rendered="{!markedCompMap['step1']}" id="step1">
    <apex:image value="/img/msg_icons/confirm32.png" />
</apex:outputPanel>